# Stripe: change plan, don't prorate unused time

Tags: stripe-payments, upgrade, invoice

**Scenario:**

On the 1st of May, the user begins his subscription at 25€/month.
On the 15th of May, he switches to an upgraded subscription at 50€/month. He is immediately invoiced 12.5€ (25€ difference - 12.5€ unused time) I believe.

**I would like the user to pay the full 25€ difference while keeping the billing period the same.**

How could I remove the "Unused time" from the equation? Is there a simple way?

*Additionally, if the user downgrades, it would be optimal if the user receives no credit to his account.*

Comment: I have exact same question. I wonder how others implement this thing

Answer (score -1):

You can set [proration_behaviour](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior) to none. Refer to https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade for more details.

Comment: This will not bill the customer.

"When prorations are disabled, customers are billed the full amount at the new price when the next invoice is generated."